# Android - GridView forcing update on data change

Tags: android, gridview

I've implemented this sample (2. Custom Adapter example)
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/
and it works.

I then wanted to "refresh" the data with a new set, which didn't work until I did this:

```
imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and then removed the following check in the ImageAdapter getView method :

```
 if (convertView == null) {
```

Here is my current getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    // if (convertView == null) {  // stopped my GridView from updating !!
    if (true)
    {
        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

        textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);


        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.square);


    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}
```

I'm concerned it is now doing unnecessary processing over and over - i.e. inflating view multiple times?

Should I be creating a new GridView every time this is called ?

Comment: just notify arraylist that you passed in adapter constructor not whole arrayadapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it didn't work because the following rows

```
   TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

    textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);


    // set image based on selected text
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.square);
```

go outside the if/else. The check `if (convertView == null)` is necessary. If you don't have it you will inflate `n` different views, with `n == getCount()`. For `n` large it will be a problem. And you probably want to implement the android [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern, to give your users the best UX possible.

As correctly pointed out by @Vzsg, get rid also of `gridView = new View(context);`. It an additional useless allocation

Comment: It might be worth to note that this line: `gridView = new View(context);` is unnecessary.

Comment: OK thanks - have retested and works fine (still) - will also investigate the ViewHolder pattern - Unfortunately I cannot mark up your answer as my reputation is too low ! Mainly coz of driveby markdowns !

Comment: So MKYONG example - although it works isn't really a good example !?

Comment: I don't read his blog and I don't usually judge others people work. If I were in you I would always read the documentation. You reputation isn't enough to vote, but you can click on the checkmark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I usually just update the adapter with the new results, and set it to the GridView.

So in your example, when I want to update my GridView - I do the following.

```
gridView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
```

You can have a utility method, such as that will make get a new Adapter much easier.

```
private ArrayAdapter getAdapter(String [] data){...}
```